# how to put - in [] in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to use `[]` to indicate a group of acceptable characters, among which is `-`. Directly putting `-` in `[]` is impossible. For example, I want to put `a-zA-Z` and `-` inside `[]`, but I cannot directly write `[a-zA-Z-]`. How should I write `-`? Using `\` to quote? Or something else?

I am using it in java.

EDIT: 
See below for answer. If you are using `-` in `[]` and feel like something is wrong, please pay attention that `-` might link two characters, and it is convention to put `-` as the last character.

Comment: "*I cannot directly write* `[a-zA-Z-]`" why? Do you get any error?

Comment: Last time I failed, maybe I wrote it in the middle and caused some confusion to the compiler. I have tested, you are right, and the answer below is also correct. Thanks! But putting - in the middle is very easy to cause confusion, for example, I have [^a-zA-Z -–], which doesn't work as expect, because - connects the space and –.

Comment: By the way, why I was downvoted?

Comment: I suspect that because your question was simply wrong, at least part where you claim that "I cannot directly write `[a-zA-Z-]`". People expect valid questions about real problems. If answer to question is "works for me" then there is definitely something wrong with such question and it needs improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* write `[a-zA-Z-]`. In fact, that's how you are supposed to do it: make the `-` the last character.

(As discussed in the comments, you are not *required* to make `-` the last character. By convention, however, it should be the last character, in order to make the regex easier to read.)

Comment: It is not that we are suppose to make `-` last character in character class. We can place it at any place which indicates that it can't be used as range operator like `[a-c-e]` represents `a-z` `-` `e` because `c` was already used to describe `a-c` range so it can't be reused to describe new range like `c-e`. So we can also write solution like `[a-z-A-Z]` here (but since such regex would be confusing people tend to place `-` at start or end of character class, or explicitly escape it with `\-`).

Comment: @Pshemo technically, you are right; you can use it elsewhere in the character class. By convention, though, it should always be the last character. As you say, it gets confusing and difficult to read otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @EdCottrell, both of you are right, putting - in the middle is possible, but it may cause confusion, and this is why I thought I cannot directly use it in the []. For example, I have [^a-zA-Z -–], which doesn't work as I expect, because - connects the space and –.